# Hibernate transaction not started

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, locking

I have an API which needs to do the following:

1. Accept concurrent requests and <s>execute them in the same order as they arrive</s> make sure only one request is executed/committed at a time.
2. Requests should be executed seperately, so as the first request is committing to database the second request should wait and as the first request completes the second request should use this updated data.

My code does the above

```
@Synchronized
@Transactional(
    readOnly = false,
    isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,
    propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,
    rollbackFor = Exception.class
)
myApi() {
    def currentSession = sessionFactory.currentSession
    def transaction = currentSession.beginTransaction()
    String query = """update table set column = :value"""
    Map params = [value: "value"]
    currentSession.doWork(new Work() {
        public void execute(Connection connection) {
            Sql sql = new Sql(connection)
            int updateCount = sql.executeUpdate(params, query)
        }
    })
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Interestingly my above code does what I want by it throws the following error:

```
| Error org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
| Error     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:665)
| Error     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
| Error     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
| Error     at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150)
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: "The same order" and "concurrent" are kind of contrary. If you are using Spring, please have a look at the following tutorial explaining how to use transactions correctly: https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/.

Comment: @AlexLiesenfeld thats correct. I've updated my question.